# Can Swagger generate a Java enum?

Tags: java, enums, swagger, swagger-editor

I have the following Swagger definition that I expect swagger-codegen will generate a Java Enum class. I have perused the swagger forums and it looks like swagger-codegen should generate the proper Java code.

```
"definitions": {
  "AnalystScoreEnum": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [
      "POOR",
      "AVERAGE"
    ]
  }
}
```

What is output from swagger-codegen is the following:

```
package io.swagger.client.model;

import io.swagger.annotations.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@ApiModel(description = "")
public class AnalystScoreEnum  {

  @Override
  public String toString()  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class AnalystScoreEnum {\n");

    sb.append("}\n");
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

What I am expecting/want is the following:

```
public enum AnalystScoresEnum {
  POOR(1),
  AVERAGE(2)

  private int value;
  private AnalystScoresEnum(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's support at the moment. Please open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues for tracking.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this issue is already in the hopper.